# How to prevent building things in other castles in multiplayer of Stronghold: Crusader?

Tags: stronghold-crusader

In `Stronghold: Crusader` anyone can build buildings in almost everywhere even near enemies building and castle. But this is a problem in fact, when enemies know this trick, they can build cheap buildings near our castle and make problem. For example, We have a castle like this:

[image]

And our enemy build something near our buildings and our units start firing at the building:

[image]

But fire based units like Fire Ballista will cause damage to our things and will cause a big fire (although it's a small fire in the picture blow):

[image]

Although Stronghold Crusader is a really good game which have multiplayer option, by knowing these tricks we won't enjoy the game.

Here are some ideas that I think can prevent this bug:

- Preventing making fire-based units: It's useless even if we don't make them, our allies (human or computer) will.
- Preventing dense building: We can't because some building should be near others.
- Making no free space available between buildings: It's hard and needs so much time and makes other problems.

What should we do?!

Comment: What about spreading some military units around? What I remember, you cannot build "too close to enemy" soldiers. (Or this apply only for military buildings?) I think this thing applied for all buildings, but I am not so sure now. Btw. few pikemen can deal with that better than balistas and without colateral damage.

Comment: @AntoineHejlík It only applies for military buildings :( they can easily build woodcutters everywhere! Isn't there any configuration settings outside of the game?

Comment: So the issue is that the fire ballista AI always auto attacks enemy structures and you can't tell it not to? I see from the wiki that this behavior was changed in later games "In Stronghold 2 and Stronghold Legends, portable fire ballistae do not fire automatically." So maybe the devs realized this was an issue for people?

Comment: @Venoda Yes they attack automatically and I can't control them specially when my aliases create them. In Stronghold 2 and Legends there is no such issue because they limit building range for every player on the map.

Comment: Yeah mods are out because apparently the AI is hardcoded. This is gonna be hard to do other than with a "gentleman's agreement" where everyone just doesn't use them.

Comment: @Venoda So there is no mod or any other method to limit building range or making all of the buildings (not just military buildings) to follow "It's too close to enemy" rule?

Comment: The wiki says no AI mods are feasible though it seems there is at least one difficulty increasing mod out there. A cursory glance of major modding sites, Stronghold Heaven, Mod DB, seems to show nothing but maps. Some games just aren't easily modded, especially if their developer never put out tools. However it's not really within this Exchange's subjects to recommend mods anyhow. Maybe try your luck on the [relevant subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/stronghold/) (though it's not very active).

Answer (score 1):

If you're playing with people you don't know, just do the same to them.
If you're playing with friends, agree on not using this strategy.

- I wasn't aware of this particular playstyle, and I'm not sure what could counter this, but **enclosing your keep will definitely help**.
- They shouldn't be able to use their fire ballista until they get an engineer to it, so **try killing the engineer before it gets to the ballista**, and destroy the ballista afterwards.
- Build a lookout tower to **maximize the range of your archers** so they can kill units from pretty far.
- **Spread out your units**, as they shouldn't be able to build near them (although this might only apply to walls and gatehouses).

**Keep in mind that they are wasting resources doing this**. Just enclose your keep and have water pots available to counter the spreading fire.

Comment: Those fire ballistas are not their units, they are mine or belongs to my aliases. Enemy build an almost free buildings near mine and my units attack them and the result is completely opposite!

Comment: Then spread your buildings to minimize fire damage and have water pots/wells available.

Comment: They can build near important buildings in any situation :(

Comment: You can always do the same to them and observe their response